# R: why is covr::package_coverage() always throws me an error starting with Error: Failure in `/tmp/RtmptOqbpy/R_LIBS5b33c260c72/....`

Tags: r, devtools, covr

I have a package that fails when i run `covr::package_coverage(quiet = FALSE, clean = FALSE)` or `devtools::test_coverage` with error message:  Error: Failure in `/tmp/RtmptOqbpy/R_LIBS5b33c260c72/package/package-tests/testthat.Rout.fail`, anyone knows why this happens? I'm on linux

Comment: A good tip is to post a summary of your problem for a title instead of an error message. That way, you get more attention.